# JScrollPane will not work no matter what Panel or Container I assign it to

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

So I've been trying to get a `JScrollPane` to work on my page but it just wont! I have a table that goes beyond the bounds set and Im trying to set it up so I can scroll down  and view everything.

I have tried adding the `JScrollPane` to all the `containers` and `panels` but it wont budge :+| - I dont see why it wont just work if I assign it to `mainCon (this.getContentPane())` because if it did work that way It would just make the whole window scrollable!

As you'll see I haven't done any Fancy layouts or anything Im just trying to get the functionality working which it is! But I need to get the JScrollPane working before I can try style all my GUIS!

Here is my code:

```
public class searchAll extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private MemTableModel memberTableModel;
    private int selectedRow;

    //JOptionPane
    //Confirm Dialog
    private int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;


    //GUI RELATED
    private JTable table = new JTable();

    //JButtons
    private JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
    private JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
    private JButton saveMember = new JButton("Save member");
    private JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");

    //Containers, panels
    Container mainCon = this.getContentPane();
    JPanel formPanel = new JPanel();

    //Adding scroll pane here - to formPanel which holds everything.
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(formPanel, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


    /*TEXT FIELDS BOXES *******************************/
    private JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name: ");
    private JTextField txtName = new JTextField("", 15);

    private JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email: ");
    private JTextField txtEmail = new JTextField("", 15);

    private JLabel lblDescription = new JLabel("Description about you: ");
    private JTextArea txtDescription = new JTextArea("", 5, 15);
    /*TEXT FIELDS BOXES *******************************/

    /*COMBO BOXES *******************************/
    private JLabel lblCountry = new JLabel();
    private JComboBox comCountry = new JComboBox();

    private JLabel lblGenre = new JLabel();
    private JComboBox comGenre = new JComboBox();
    /*COMBO BOXES *******************************/

    /*RADIO BUTTONS *******************************/
    private JLabel lblMaleFemale = new JLabel("Gender: ");
    private JRadioButton radMale = new JRadioButton("Male: ");
    private JRadioButton radFemale = new JRadioButton("Female: ");
    private ButtonGroup buttonGroupMF = new ButtonGroup();

    private JLabel lblFreePaid = new JLabel("Membership Type: ");
    private JRadioButton radFree = new JRadioButton("Free: ");
    private JRadioButton radPaid = new JRadioButton("Paid: ");
    private ButtonGroup buttonGroupFP = new ButtonGroup();
    /*RADIO BUTTONS *******************************/

    /*PAID MEMBER STUFF *******************************/
    private JLabel lblCardNo = new JLabel("Card Number: ");
    private JTextField txtCardNo = new JTextField("", 15);

    private JLabel lblExpiry = new JLabel();
    private JComboBox comExpiry = new JComboBox();
    /*PAID MEMBER STUFF *******************************/

    //DB SQL Variables - 
    private String edName = "";
    private String edEmail = "";
    private String edDescription = "";
    private String edCountry = "";
    private String edGenre = "";
    private String edGender = "";
    private String edMembType = "";
    private String edCardNo = "";
    private Object edExpiry = "";
    private String edSongLim = "";

    //DB 
    private Connection conDB = null;
    private Statement stmt = null;
    private ResultSet r = null;

    //Validation isValid
    private boolean isValid;

    public searchAll(){
        super("Search/Edit/Delete");
        this.setBounds(400, 500, 854,400);
//        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        this.setVisible(true);
        memberTableModel = new MemTableModel();

        //Add table and GUI components
        mainCon.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, btnBack);
        btnBack.addActionListener(this);
        mainCon.add(scrollPane);
        mainCon.add(formPanel);
        formPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));


        formPanel.add(table);
        formPanel.add(btnDelete);
        formPanel.add(btnEdit);
        //Tried doing this - But didn't work. Just stayed static
//        formPanel.add(scrollPane);

        //Add action listeners

        btnEdit.addActionListener(this);
        btnDelete.addActionListener(this);
        table.setModel(memberTableModel);

        //Set Selection model for table
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        ListSelectionModel rowSM = table.getSelectionModel();
        rowSM.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()  {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
                ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
                selectedRow = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
                System.out.println(selectedRow);
            }
        });

    }


    //Connection Method
    public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection conDB = null;
         /****** DEFAULT MYSQL DRIVERS **************************/
            String url = connection.geturl();
            String username = connection.getUsername();
            String password = connection.getPassword();
        try{
            //load the MYSQL driver
            Class.forName(connection.getDriver());
            conDB = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error was: " + e);
        }
         return conDB;
    }

    /*-------ACTION PERFORMED ------------------------------*/
    int editCounter = 0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == btnBack){
            this.dispose();
        }

                            //DELETE BUTTON BELOW
/*########################################################################*/

        if(e.getSource() == btnDelete){

            System.out.println("Ran btnDelete");
            deleteMember();

        }
/*########################################################################*/

                        //EDIT BUTTON BELOW

/*########################################################################*/

        if(e.getSource() == btnEdit){
            if(editCounter == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Ran btnEdit");
                editFunction();
                editCounter++;
            }
             else{
                formPanel.repaint();
                System.out.println("Stop duplicating form inputs");
            }

        }
/*########################################################################*/

                        //SAVE MEMBER BUTTON BELOW

/*########################################################################*/
        if(e.getSource() == saveMember){
            System.out.println("Ran btnSaveMember");
             //UPDATE VALUES
                if(radMale.isSelected()){
                    edGender = "Male";
                }
                else if(radFemale.isSelected()){
                    edGender = "Female";
                }
                if(radPaid.isSelected()){
                    edMembType = "Paid";
                    edSongLim = "100";
                    edCardNo = txtCardNo.getText();
                    edExpiry = comExpiry.getSelectedItem();
                    txtCardNo.setEnabled(true);

                }
                else{
                    edMembType = "Free";
                    edSongLim = "10";
                    edCardNo = "";
                    edExpiry = "";
                    txtCardNo.setEnabled(false);

                }
           //Validate the form
           if(txtName.getText().equals(""))
           {
               isValid = false;
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a name please");
           }
           else{
               isValid = true;
                if(txtEmail.getText().equals("")){
                  isValid = false; 
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter an Email please");
               }
               else
               {
                   isValid = true;
                    if(txtDescription.getText().equals("")){
                      isValid = false; 
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a Description please");
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       isValid = true;
                       if(radPaid.isSelected()){
                           if(txtCardNo.getText().equals("")){
                               isValid = false; 
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a Card Number please");
                           }
                           else{
                               isValid = true;
                           }
                       }

                   }
               }
           }
           //If the form is good, execute the update
           if(isValid){
            saveMember();
           }
        }//End of saveMember Button
}//End of action performed
 /*########################################################################*/      

                           //DELETE MEMBER BELOW

/*#######################DELETE MEMBER####################################*/
    public void deleteMember(){
        member m  =  memberTableModel.getRow(selectedRow);       
        System.out.println("in BTN delete");
            try{
            //Connection + Statement
            conDB = getConnection();
            stmt = conDB.createStatement();
            String sqlDeleteMem = "delete from members where membId = " + m.getmembId();

            //Confirm Dialog - If they click yes dialogResult will = 0
            int dialogResult = 
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you want to delete " + m.getname()
            , "Delete Confirmation", dialogButton);
            String sqlDeletePlay = "delete from playlist where membId = " + m.getmembId();
             if(dialogResult == 0){
                stmt.executeUpdate(sqlDeleteMem);
                //Delete the playlists associated with the member.
                stmt.executeUpdate(sqlDeletePlay);
                System.out.println(m.getname() + " Deleted");
             }
             else{
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, m.getname() + " was not deleted");
             }

            //Close the DB connection
//            stmt.close();
//            conDB.close();


            }
            catch(SQLException er){
                System.out.println("Error was: " + er);
            }
            memberTableModel.LoadTableFromDB();
            memberTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(selectedRow, selectedRow);
    }

/*#########################################################################*/

                        //SAVE MEMBER BELOW

/*#######################SAVE MEMBER####################################*/
    public void saveMember(){
        member m  =  memberTableModel.getRow(selectedRow);       
         System.out.println("Save member 1");

            try{
             //CHANGE THE VALUES SO WHEN CLICKS SAVE MEM

                /*-------------------------------------*/   


            //Connection + Statement
            conDB = getConnection();
            stmt = conDB.createStatement();

            //Update Query
            String sqlUpdateMem = "UPDATE members SET name = '" + txtName.getText() + "', " + 
            "email = '" + txtEmail.getText() + "', "
            + "country = '" + comCountry.getSelectedItem() + "', "
            + "favGenre = '" + comGenre.getSelectedItem() + "', "
            + "gender = '" + edGender + "', "
            + "description = '" + txtDescription.getText() + "', "
            + "memberType = '" + edMembType + "', "
            + "songLimit = '" + edSongLim + "', "
            + "card_no = '" +  edCardNo + "', "
            + "expiry_date = '" + edExpiry + "' WHERE membId = '"
                    + m.getmembId() + "'";
            System.out.println(sqlUpdateMem);


            System.out.println("Save member 2");

            stmt.executeUpdate(sqlUpdateMem);
            editCounter = 0;

            System.out.println("Updated Member");
            //Close the DB connection
            conDB.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException er){
                System.out.println("Error was: " + er);
            }
    }
/*###########################################################################*/

                        //ADD INPUT FIELDS BELOW

 /*#######################INPUT FIELDS####################################*/   
    public void showInputFields(){
        formPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

         /*TEXT FIELDS BOXES *******************************/
        formPanel.add(lblName);
        formPanel.add(txtName);

        formPanel.add(lblEmail);
        formPanel.add(txtEmail);

        formPanel.add(lblDescription);
        formPanel.add(txtDescription);
        /*TEXT FIELDS BOXES *******************************/



        /*COMBO BOXES *******************************/

        //Combo Box ( Countrys )
        formPanel.add(lblCountry);
        formPanel.add(comCountry);
        comCountry.addItem("Australia");
        comCountry.addItem("New Zealand");
        comCountry.addItem("Tasmania");
        comCountry.addActionListener(this);
        //Combo Box ( Fav Genre )
        formPanel.add(lblGenre);
        formPanel.add(comGenre);
        comGenre.addItem("Pop");
        comGenre.addItem("Rock");
        comGenre.addItem("Alternative");
        comGenre.addItem("Jazz");
        comGenre.addItem("Hip/Hop");

        comGenre.addActionListener(this);

        /*COMBO BOXES *******************************/


        /*RADIO BUTTONS BOXES *******************************/
        //Radio Buttons (Male/Female)
        buttonGroupMF.add(radMale);
        buttonGroupMF.add(radFemale);

        formPanel.add(radMale);
        formPanel.add(radFemale);

        radMale.addActionListener(this);
        radFemale.addActionListener(this);

        //Free or paid members ------ 
        buttonGroupFP.add(radFree);
        buttonGroupFP.add(radPaid);

        formPanel.add(radFree);
        formPanel.add(radPaid);

        radFree.addActionListener(this);
        radPaid.addActionListener(this);
        //Free or paid members ------ 
        /*RADIO BUTTONS BOXES *******************************/


        /*PAID MEMBER GUI *******************************/


        formPanel.add(lblCardNo);
        formPanel.add(txtCardNo);
        //Hide
        lblCardNo.setVisible(true);
        txtCardNo.setVisible(true);


        formPanel.add(lblExpiry);
        formPanel.add(comExpiry);
        comExpiry.addItem("2017");
        comExpiry.addItem("2018");
        comExpiry.addItem("2019");

        //Hide
        lblExpiry.setVisible(true);
        comExpiry.setVisible(true);
        comExpiry.addActionListener(this);

        /*PAID MEMBER GUI *******************************/

        //Add the button after everything
        formPanel.add(saveMember);
        saveMember.addActionListener(this);
    }
/*###########################################################################*/

                        //EDIT MEMBER BELOW

 /*#######################EDIT MEMBER####################################*/
    public void editFunction(){

            member m  =  memberTableModel.getRow(selectedRow);       
            System.out.println("in BTN edit 1");
            //Add boolean value here - Can submit
            showInputFields();
            try{
                System.out.println(" hihi" +  m.getmembId());
            //Connection + Statement
            conDB = getConnection();
            stmt = conDB.createStatement();
            System.out.println(" hihi" +  m.getmembId());
            System.out.println("in BTN edit 2");
            String sqlEdit = "select * from members where membId = " + m.getmembId();

            r = stmt.executeQuery(sqlEdit);
            System.out.println("in BTN edit 3");
            if(r.next()){
                System.out.println("in BTN edit 4");
                //Set text for each TextField - Also assign the values to variables
                //The variables are used in the SQL UPDATE Query.
                //SET THE VALUES FOR THE INPUT FIELDS FROM DB ----------
                txtName.setText(r.getString("name"));
                txtEmail.setText(r.getString("email"));
                txtDescription.setText(r.getString("description"));
                comCountry.setSelectedItem(r.getString("country"));
                comGenre.setSelectedItem(r.getString("favGenre"));
                txtCardNo.setText(r.getString("card_no"));
                comExpiry.setSelectedItem(r.getString("expiry_date"));
                if(r.getString("memberType").equals("Paid")){
                    radPaid.setSelected(true);
                }
                else{
                    radFree.setSelected(true);
                }
                if(r.getString("gender").equals("Male")){
                    radMale.setSelected(true);
//                    edGender = "Male";
                }
                else{
                    radFemale.setSelected(true);
//                    edGender = "Female";
                }
                //---------------------------------------------------------
                System.out.println("in BTN edit 5");
            }            
        }
            catch(SQLException er){
                System.out.println("Error was: " + er);
            }
            memberTableModel.LoadTableFromDB();
            System.out.println("in BTN edit 6");
            System.out.println("in BTN edit 7");
    }
/*##########################################################################*/


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JPanel formPanel = new JPanel();

//Adding scroll pane here - to formPanel which holds everything.
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(formPanel, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

...

mainCon.add(scrollPane);
mainCon.add(formPanel);
```

You should not reaffect `formPanel` in the code (It'll lose its already assigned parent), just add `scrollPane` that already contains your `formPanel`

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        new SearchAll().setVisible(true);

    }

    public static class SearchAll extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        private int selectedRow;

        //JOptionPane
        //Confirm Dialog
        private int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;


        //GUI RELATED
        private JTable table = new JTable();

        //JButtons
        private JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        private JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
        private JButton saveMember = new JButton("Save member");
        private JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");

        //Containers, panels
        Container mainCon = this.getContentPane();
        JPanel formPanel = new JPanel();

        //Adding scroll pane here - to formPanel which holds everything.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(formPanel, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


        /*TEXT FIELDS BOXES *******************************/
        private JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name: ");
        private JTextField txtName = new JTextField("", 15);

        private JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email: ");
        private JTextField txtEmail = new JTextField("", 15);

        private JLabel lblDescription = new JLabel("Description about you: ");
        private JTextArea txtDescription = new JTextArea("", 5, 15);
        /*TEXT FIELDS BOXES *******************************/

        /*COMBO BOXES *******************************/
        private JLabel lblCountry = new JLabel();
        private JComboBox comCountry = new JComboBox();

        private JLabel lblGenre = new JLabel();
        private JComboBox comGenre = new JComboBox();
        /*COMBO BOXES *******************************/

        /*RADIO BUTTONS *******************************/
        private JLabel lblMaleFemale = new JLabel("Gender: ");
        private JRadioButton radMale = new JRadioButton("Male: ");
        private JRadioButton radFemale = new JRadioButton("Female: ");
        private ButtonGroup buttonGroupMF = new ButtonGroup();

        private JLabel lblFreePaid = new JLabel("Membership Type: ");
        private JRadioButton radFree = new JRadioButton("Free: ");
        private JRadioButton radPaid = new JRadioButton("Paid: ");
        private ButtonGroup buttonGroupFP = new ButtonGroup();
        /*RADIO BUTTONS *******************************/

        /*PAID MEMBER STUFF *******************************/
        private JLabel lblCardNo = new JLabel("Card Number: ");
        private JTextField txtCardNo = new JTextField("", 15);

        private JLabel lblExpiry = new JLabel();
        private JComboBox comExpiry = new JComboBox();
        /*PAID MEMBER STUFF *******************************/

        //DB SQL Variables - 
        private String edName = "";
        private String edEmail = "";
        private String edDescription = "";
        private String edCountry = "";
        private String edGenre = "";
        private String edGender = "";
        private String edMembType = "";
        private String edCardNo = "";
        private Object edExpiry = "";
        private String edSongLim = "";

        //DB 
        private Connection conDB = null;
        private Statement stmt = null;
        private ResultSet r = null;

        //Validation isValid
        private boolean isValid;

        public SearchAll(){
            super("Search/Edit/Delete");
            this.setBounds(400, 500, 854,400);
//            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
            this.setVisible(true);

            //Add table and GUI components
            mainCon.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, btnBack);
            btnBack.addActionListener(this);
            mainCon.add(scrollPane);


            formPanel.add(table);
            formPanel.add(btnDelete);
            formPanel.add(btnEdit);
            //Tried doing this - But didn't work. Just stayed static
//            formPanel.add(scrollPane);

            //Add action listeners

            btnEdit.addActionListener(this);
            btnDelete.addActionListener(this);

            //Set Selection model for table
            table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(100, 8));

            ListSelectionModel rowSM = table.getSelectionModel();
            rowSM.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()  {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
                    ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
                    selectedRow = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
                    System.out.println(selectedRow);
                }
            });

        }


        /*-------ACTION PERFORMED ------------------------------*/
        int editCounter = 0;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == btnBack){
                this.dispose();
            }

                                //DELETE BUTTON BELOW
    /*########################################################################*/

            if(e.getSource() == btnDelete){

                System.out.println("Ran btnDelete");
            }
    /*########################################################################*/

                            //EDIT BUTTON BELOW

    /*########################################################################*/

            if(e.getSource() == btnEdit){
                if(editCounter == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Ran btnEdit");
                    editCounter++;
                }
                 else{
                    formPanel.repaint();
                    System.out.println("Stop duplicating form inputs");
                }

            }
    /*########################################################################*/

                            //SAVE MEMBER BUTTON BELOW

    /*########################################################################*/
            if(e.getSource() == saveMember){
                System.out.println("Ran btnSaveMember");
                 //UPDATE VALUES
                    if(radMale.isSelected()){
                        edGender = "Male";
                    }
                    else if(radFemale.isSelected()){
                        edGender = "Female";
                    }
                    if(radPaid.isSelected()){
                        edMembType = "Paid";
                        edSongLim = "100";
                        edCardNo = txtCardNo.getText();
                        edExpiry = comExpiry.getSelectedItem();
                        txtCardNo.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                    else{
                        edMembType = "Free";
                        edSongLim = "10";
                        edCardNo = "";
                        edExpiry = "";
                        txtCardNo.setEnabled(false);

                    }
               //Validate the form
               if(txtName.getText().equals(""))
               {
                   isValid = false;
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a name please");
               }
               else{
                   isValid = true;
                    if(txtEmail.getText().equals("")){
                      isValid = false; 
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter an Email please");
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       isValid = true;
                        if(txtDescription.getText().equals("")){
                          isValid = false; 
                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a Description please");
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           isValid = true;
                           if(radPaid.isSelected()){
                               if(txtCardNo.getText().equals("")){
                                   isValid = false; 
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a Card Number please");
                               }
                               else{
                                   isValid = true;
                               }
                           }

                       }
                   }
               }
               //If the form is good, execute the update
               if(isValid){
               }
            }//End of saveMember Button
    }//End of action performed
     /*########################################################################*/      

                               //DELETE MEMBER BELOW

    /*#######################DELETE MEMBER####################################*/

    /*#########################################################################*/

                            //SAVE MEMBER BELOW

    /*#######################SAVE MEMBER####################################*/
    /*###########################################################################*/

                            //ADD INPUT FIELDS BELOW

     /*#######################INPUT FIELDS####################################*/   
        public void showInputFields(){
            formPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

             /*TEXT FIELDS BOXES *******************************/
            formPanel.add(lblName);
            formPanel.add(txtName);

            formPanel.add(lblEmail);
            formPanel.add(txtEmail);

            formPanel.add(lblDescription);
            formPanel.add(txtDescription);
            /*TEXT FIELDS BOXES *******************************/



            /*COMBO BOXES *******************************/

            //Combo Box ( Countrys )
            formPanel.add(lblCountry);
            formPanel.add(comCountry);
            comCountry.addItem("Australia");
            comCountry.addItem("New Zealand");
            comCountry.addItem("Tasmania");
            comCountry.addActionListener(this);
            //Combo Box ( Fav Genre )
            formPanel.add(lblGenre);
            formPanel.add(comGenre);
            comGenre.addItem("Pop");
            comGenre.addItem("Rock");
            comGenre.addItem("Alternative");
            comGenre.addItem("Jazz");
            comGenre.addItem("Hip/Hop");

            comGenre.addActionListener(this);

            /*COMBO BOXES *******************************/


            /*RADIO BUTTONS BOXES *******************************/
            //Radio Buttons (Male/Female)
            buttonGroupMF.add(radMale);
            buttonGroupMF.add(radFemale);

            formPanel.add(radMale);
            formPanel.add(radFemale);

            radMale.addActionListener(this);
            radFemale.addActionListener(this);

            //Free or paid members ------ 
            buttonGroupFP.add(radFree);
            buttonGroupFP.add(radPaid);

            formPanel.add(radFree);
            formPanel.add(radPaid);

            radFree.addActionListener(this);
            radPaid.addActionListener(this);
            //Free or paid members ------ 
            /*RADIO BUTTONS BOXES *******************************/


            /*PAID MEMBER GUI *******************************/


            formPanel.add(lblCardNo);
            formPanel.add(txtCardNo);
            //Hide
            lblCardNo.setVisible(true);
            txtCardNo.setVisible(true);


            formPanel.add(lblExpiry);
            formPanel.add(comExpiry);
            comExpiry.addItem("2017");
            comExpiry.addItem("2018");
            comExpiry.addItem("2019");

            //Hide
            lblExpiry.setVisible(true);
            comExpiry.setVisible(true);
            comExpiry.addActionListener(this);

            /*PAID MEMBER GUI *******************************/

            //Add the button after everything
            formPanel.add(saveMember);
            saveMember.addActionListener(this);
        }
    /*###########################################################################*/

                            //EDIT MEMBER BELOW

     /*#######################EDIT MEMBER####################################*/
    /*##########################################################################*/


    }
}
```

Comment: ahh for some reason this didn't fix it! But I get what you mean.

Comment: Remove `formPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));` you should only give a size to the ScrollPane.

Comment: Yeah I've tried removing a lot of things including the `prefferedsize` and it still isn't working. Which is annoying :P

Comment: @James111 I copied your project and applied modification and it works, Vertical scrollbar is there. Note that `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` will hide the scrollbar but is not meant to force panel to rearrange. So in your case, you may lose some button if they're too much on the right side. Copy/Paste the code I attached and try it.

Comment: Thanks for putting time into it! Now I know your suppose to add `JScrollPanes`